# Converting big JSON-file to XML

Tags: java, json, xml, string, buffer

I'm trying to convert a json-file to xml using json.org library which converts strings. However I've a big file that I can't store in cache so I want to write as I convert. Anyone have any ideas of how I should go about?

So far:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_NAME));
private String line;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(line));
    String xml = XML.toString(json);
    // Write on OUTPUT_FILE_NAME
}
```

Comment: Is the file one big json object, or a ton of smaller objects?

Comment: One big json-file (3gb) @ParrisVarney

Comment: Can you remove the first and last curly bracket, read the sub objects into memory one by one, build the xml, then paste everything together at the end?

Comment: @ParrisVarney, thanks! How would I do that practically? Wouldn't that store all the data in the cache?

Comment: I guess you could write a parser that reads your file byte by byte and writes to several small files when it finds a full subobject.  You could use a directory structure similar to your object hierarchy.

Comment: Depending on how deep this json is nested you might have a fun recursion exercise on your hands

Answer (score 1):

If you are not tied to `json.org` you could always try the low level streaming with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and the json to xml support in [jackson-dataformat-xml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

```
    JsonFactory jf = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser jp = jf.createParser(...);

    XmlFactory xf = new XmlFactory();
    JsonGenerator xg = xf.createGenerator(...);

    xg.writeFieldName("root"); // need a root element

    JsonToken t = null;
    while((t = jp.nextToken()) != null) {
        switch(t) {
        case START_OBJECT:
            xg.writeStartObject();
            break;
        case END_OBJECT:
            xg.writeEndObject();
            break;
        case START_ARRAY:
            xg.writeStartArray();
            break;
        case END_ARRAY:
            xg.writeEndArray();
            break;
        case FIELD_NAME:
            xg.writeFieldName(jp.getCurrentName());
            break;
        case VALUE_STRING:
            xg.writeString(jp.getText());
            break;
        case VALUE_FALSE:
            xg.writeBoolean(false);
            break;
        case VALUE_TRUE:
            xg.writeBoolean(true);
            break;
        // some tokens missing here
        }
    }
```